# What can cause this difference between prod and dev?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2, app-engine-ndb

Same code, in production don't work while in development yes.

models:

```py
class Comput(ndb.Model):
    @staticmethod
    def membership(user):
        q = ndb.gql("SELECT * FROM Members WHERE member = :1", user)
        result = q.fetch()
        return [m.comput.get() for m in result]
        #return [m.comput.get() for m in q] #same issue (dev yes, prod no)

class Members(ndb.Model):
    comput = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Comput)
    member = ndb.UserProperty()
```

handler:

```py
comput_list = Comput.membership(users.get_current_user())
```

template:

```py
{% for comput in comput_list %}
    <tr onclick="location.href='/comput?id={$ comput.key.id() $}'">
```

Traceback (only in production):

```py
UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'key'
```

This appears even when `comput_list` have entities.

update: No autogenerate index for Members, I tried to add manually but nothing changes

Comment: Just to be sure:  What code line throws the error? And do you have data in the table in production?

Comment: the line is the `<tr onclick...`. I'm sure that the data is in the tables.

Comment: seems that comput_list return `None`. Anyway I expected empty templates, no errors

Comment: Yeah that was my guess and why I asked about data in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like one of your `Members` objects has None for its `comput` property. I would use the production data viewer (or add a log statements) to find which member it is.

Comment: Yes! The function that delete the Comput entities don't delete also the referenced Members entities. Then I had a Members entity with a comput property that link to a missed Comput entity.